# php mysql INSERT INTO mysql by using register form

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I am php beginner and I am trying to make e-commerce by using php.
I am trying to make register form and I want to save these data into mysql server.
The coding looks like OK, but the data did not store in mysql server.
Could you give your answer for this? php language is first time that it is what I am struggled. Please give some advice. Thanks.

--registerForm.php--

```
<h4>Create a new account</h4>
                <div class="box">
                <form action="register.php" method="post">
                    <p>User ID: <input type="text" name="userId" size="30"/>*</p>
                    <p>Password: <input type="password" name="password" size="30"/>*</p>
                    <p>Retype Password: <input type="password" name="repassword" size="30"/>*</p>
                    <p>First Name: <input type="text" name="firstName" size="30"/>*</p>
                    <p>Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastName" size="30"/>*</p>
                    <p>Your Address (*):</p>
                    <p> <textarea name="address" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea></p>
                    <p>Phone: <input type="text" name="phone" size="20"/>*</p>
                    <p>E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" size="21"/>*</p>
                    <p><input type="submit" value="Create Account"/></p>
                </form>
                </div>
```

--register.php--

```
<?php
require "sql_connection.php";
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
if($_GET["userId"]==$_GET["repassword"]){
mysql_query("insert into customer (userId, password, firstName, lastName, address,
phone, email) 
values
  ('$_GET[userId]','$_GET[password]','$_GET[firstName]','$_GET[lastName]','$_GET[address]','$_GET[phone]','$_GET[email]')")
or die(mysql_error());
}
echo "Done!!!!";
}
?>
```

--sql_connection.php--

```
<?php
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_username = "root";
$db_pass = "**MY_PASS**";
$db_name = "**MY_DB**";

@mysql_connect("$db_host", "$db_username", "$db_pass", "$db_name") or die("connection is fail.");
@mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die("database does not exsist.");
echo "Successfully connection!!";
?>
```

Comment: @Marshall: note that the origina username and password are saved in the post history -- leaked is forever.

Comment: Please note that you have written a script that is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerabilities because you have not sanitized any of the user-supplied variables in your SQL queries. Please use [PHP Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to prevent these vulnerabilities. Thanks.

Comment: O_o oh well. Sooooo @wholee1 even though this is on your localhost, I'd change the database name & password - better now than forget to later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if($_GET["userId"]==$_GET["repassword"])
```

Why do you compare userid to a retype pssword field?

I think it should be :

```
if($_GET["password"]==$_GET["repassword"])
```

Also make sure you escape strings to prevent SQL Injection Attacks.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

And Like Paul said, to correctly retrieve the data use $_POST

Answer (score 3):

Few things. Your `$_GET` and `$_POST` are mixed up. and NEVER post your db_pass and uername in public. Also, you're suppressing errors using `@`. don't do that.

i.e.

```
if($_GET["userId"]==$_GET["repassword"]){
```

should be

```
if($_POST["userId"]==$_POST["repassword"]){
```

and changes all these to `$_POST`

Your code:

```
$_GET[userId]','$_GET[password]','$_GET[firstName]','$_GET[lastName]','$_GET[address]','$_GET[phone]','$_GET[email]')
```

Should be:

```
$_POST[userId]','$_POST[password]','$_POST[firstName]','$_POST[lastName]','$_POST[address]','$_POST[phone]','$_POST[email]')"
```

Answer (score 3):

As your form method  defined is `POST` so use `$_POST` to get values after submit instead of `$_GET`

```
require "sql_connection.php";
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
if($_POST["userId"]==$_POST["repassword"]){
mysql_query("insert into customer (userId, password, firstName, lastName, address,
phone, email) 
values
  ('$_POST[userId]','$_POST[password]','$_POST[firstName]','$_POST[lastName]','$_POST[address]','$_POST[phone]','$_POST[email]')")
or die(mysql_error());
}
echo "Done!!!!";
}
?>
```

Values are not quoted properly. You should quote then before insert.

```
mysql_query("insert into customer (userId, password, firstName, lastName, address,
phone, email) 
values
  ('".$_POST[userId]."','".$_POST[password]."','".$_POST[firstName]."','".$_POST[lastName]."','".$_POST[address]."','".$_POST[phone]."','".$_POST[email]."')")
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, but still it is not insert into customer table.. what is problem?

Comment: You should either ask in new question or update this question

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are trying to do is:

```
if($_GET["password"]==$_GET["repassword"]) {
```